# How to Enable registration email for a custom user role?

Tags: user-roles, email, user-registration

I have created a custom user role that named as Teacher.

```
add_role('teacher',
            'Trainer',
            array(
                'read' => true,
                'edit_posts' => false,
                'delete_posts' => false,
                'publish_posts' => false,
                'upload_files' => true,
            )
        );
```

Everything work fine. But when creating a new teacher by admin the user registration email is not sent automatically. How can I enable that?

Comment: Have you checked the "Send the new user an email about their account" box during creation? Do other emails work fine?

Comment: @Stefano Tombolini, Yes, all emails work fine including user creation for other default WordPress user types.